# Make a div be added to an element with the .add() jQuery method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this code that can create `<div></div>'s` that are draggable. I'm trying to make the draggable `<div></div>'s` be able to be dropped in any `<td></td>` and have the dragged div be deleted.

**Right now I have 1 problem:**

1. the dragged div isn't "dropped" into the `<td></td>`

So, I have one question: Is there a way to make a div be added to an element with the .add() jQuery method?

**Kind of of like below (I tried this but it didn't work):**

```
  $( "td" ).add("<div>"+ text +"</div>");
```

**In more detail this is what my program aims to do:**

User inputs some text and clicks input -> the users input is outputted as a draggable `<div></div>` -> the draggable div is able to be dropped into a `<td></td>`

Here is my full code:

```js
function addElement () { 
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  // create a new div element 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");  

  // and give it some content 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

    $(function() {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); 
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

    $(div).draggable();

    $(td).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find("td").append("<div>"+ text +"</div>");
        $(this).find("div").remove();
      }
    });

  });

    document.getElementById("input").value = " ";

}
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 20px ;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}


.div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px ;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Input text:</h1>
    <input id="input"type="text" placeholder=" input">
    <button onclick="addElement()" >input</button>   

    <p>Drag your outputs to the div:</p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width=100></td>
    <td width=100></td>
    <td width=100></td>
  </tr>
</table>


     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Update:

I changed this:

```
$(td).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find("td").append("<div>"+ text +"</div>");
        $(this).find("div").remove();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Also, use a modern jQuery version. `1-12.4` is very old. And if you're using jQuery, you might want to skip creating elements using vanilla JS.

Comment: it's not `$(...).add(...)` it's  `$(...).append(...)` in this case since you're adding a fully formed element.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Apart from wrognly assigning the elements. everything else is fine. You are not assigning the `div` and `td` elements properly and removing all of them of the same type by the `remove` function.

```
function addElement () { 
  
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  
  // create a new div element and give it a unique id
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id = 'temp'

  // and give it some content
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

  $(function() {
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

    $("#temp").draggable();

    $(td).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) { console.log($(this))
          $( this ).append("<div>"+ text +"</div>");
          $( "#temp" ).remove();
      }
    });

  });

  document.getElementById("input").value = " ";

}
```

This is further scope for optimizing this. I insist you explore the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I'll be sure to read the documentation!

Answer (score -1):

your like   $( "div" ).remove(); is removing all divs present on page. that will include any newest div that your js is creating. You need to identify div that you are dragging and remove that specific instance instead of all divs on page.

Comment: Make a runnable snippet

Comment: good catch, I'm aware of that! I was going to ask about that next, do you have any idea how I could identify the div that is dropped into a td?

Comment: @hp2345 you can try `$(this).find("div").remove()`

Comment: @HymnZzy Okay! I made the changes (you can also see them in my post), but it still dosent 'work is this syntax correct: `$(td).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).find("td").append("<div>"+ text +"</div>");
        $(this).find("div").remove();
      }
    }); `

Answer (score -1):

Good read: https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

Hope this code will solve your problem
Firstly, we need added `droppable` in jQuery:

```
$(td).droppable({
tolerance: 'fit'
});
```

Because `td` is your Dropped `div`

**Then**, Added `draggable` like this

**From:**

```
$(div).draggable();
```

**To:**

```
$(div).draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
  stop: function(){
    $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
  }
});
```

This is make a `div` **Draggable**

After it, use this code for tell their `Droppable` property
**From:**

```
$(td).droppable({
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    $( this )
      $( "td" ).add("<div>"+ text +"</div>");
      $( "div" ).remove();
  }
});
```

**To:**

```
$(div).droppable({
  greedy: true,
   tolerance: 'touch',
   drop: function(event,ui){
   ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
   $("td").append("<div>"+ text +"</div>");
   $("div").remove();
   }
});
```

Why I changed `td` to `div`??
Because your **draggable** is `div` and dropped to `td`.
And I'm removed `$(this)` from `droppable` and changed `.add` to `.append`.

This output snippet

```js
function addElement () { 
  var text = document.getElementById("input").value;
  // create a new div element 
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");  

  // and give it some content 
  var newContent = document.createTextNode(text); 
  
  // add the text node to the newly created div
  newDiv.appendChild(newContent);  

  // add the newly created element and its content into the DOM 
  var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
  document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv); 

    $(function() {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); 
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    $(td).droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit'
    });
    $(div).draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
    });

    $(div).droppable({
      greedy: true,
       tolerance: 'touch',
       drop: function(event,ui){
       ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
       $("td").append("<div>"+ text +"</div>");
       $("div").remove();
       }
    });

  });

    document.getElementById("input").value = " ";

}
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 20px ;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  color: #fff;
}


.div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}

td{
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 20px ;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<h1>Input text:</h1>
    <input id="input"type="text" placeholder=" input">
    <button onclick="addElement()" >input</button>   

    <p>Drag your outputs to the div:</p>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width=100></td>
    <td width=100></td>
    <td width=100></td>
  </tr>
</table>


     <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: As a practice, when external plugins are being used, please add a line to explain why you are proposing a new code for all future references.

Comment: I only explain the structure first, then I will update it when it is approved. Because, firstly, to make it easier to understand for those who have problems, to solve problems more quickly if what I provide can solve the problem.

Comment: In that case, your answer is wrong as it's not providing the required solution to the OP.

Comment: Are you reading this? *the dragged div isn't "dropped" into the <td></td>* ??

Comment: Your solution doesn't append the element to the respective `td` where it is dropped. Hence the more reason I asked you to provide the reason why you are proposing a different code.

Comment: There are three `td` and the problem is you can't drag it to `td`. so I use this code because this is the problem. You can see, and try to add 4 `div` will remove! [https://prnt.sc/w0yaeu](https://prnt.sc/w0yaeu)